# App redirects to Account/AccessDenied on adding Oauth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've stumbled upon an issue where inconsistently the application redirects the user to `Account/AccessDenied/` upon adding a social media authentication to the current logged in user. It seems to work the first time the user is logged in, then by trying to add another authentication method it returns the user to                               `Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2Fmanage%2Flinklogincallback`.

My guess is that something is going wrong with the [Authorize] attribute, but only the second time I try adding external authentication method.

**ManageController**

```
[Authorize]
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    //
    // POST: /Manage/LinkLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Manage");
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, _userManager.GetUserId(User));
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Manage/LinkLoginCallback
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
    {
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ManageLogins), new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }
        var result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
        var message = result.Succeeded ? ManageMessageId.AddLoginSuccess : ManageMessageId.Error;
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ManageLogins), new { Message = message });
    }
}
```

Could it be the order of how startup.cs is arranged?

**This is the request/response**

[image]

Comment: Is this error happening consistently?
Because I got this error a lot when my code was still throwing buggy exceptions. Clearing the cookies fixed the problem temporarily.  Later when I fixed my trivial bugs, this redirectd no longer occurred.

Comment: It happens consistently, but I dont have a clue what it is as everything else works as intended. What was your trivial bugs you fixed to make it work?

Comment: Have you added `app.UseGoogleAuthentication(...)` in your `Configure()` method of the `Startup` class?

Comment: My bug was some exception thrown once after OAuth challenge, but before associating Faceboook login with user. So I ended up with browser cookies with Claims of an unexistent user. Clearing cookies and DELETE FROM USERS table did the trick.  Try to do that, reset your DB and cookies.

Comment: I also went to Facebook as a user (not as a developer) and deleted the app from my profile and tried again. Not sure that can be done with Google.

Comment: How do you mean reset db and cookie each time? That seems very odd... I had this working at early stages of development without errors...

Comment: Not each time. Just do it once. It failed to me when I invoked the challenge after another failed challenge (If there is a principal already on the cookie.)
Did you cleared cookies and users once on your machine to test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got confirmed by aspnet team working on Security repo that this is a bug (see this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/980)) and resolved until next release.
A temporary workaround is to set a cookie named

> Identity.External

to null, which is created upon adding external login to your account.

```
if (Request.Cookies["Identity.External"] != null)
{
     Response.Cookies.Delete("Identity.External"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the link to the github issue please?

Comment: Updated answer with link, @GerardoGrignoli

Comment: I was also experiencing the issue, but after I upgraded to 1.1.0 it works even without the workaround

Answer (score 6):

@Rovdjuret's workaround helped me until it’s resolved by asp.net team. Here is my controller Login action:

```
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl = null)
{
    if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        // redirect to user profile page
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeFileController.Index), "HomeFile");                
    }
    else
    {
        // clear Identity.External cookie
        if (Request.Cookies["Identity.External"] != null)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete("Identity.External");
        }
        return View(new LoginViewModel{ ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = true });
    }
}
```

Update: In the latest version (as of May 2017) the cookies have prefix ".AspNetCore.". So cookie name should be "**.AspNetCore.Identity.External**"

Answer (score 5):

I too faced the same issue. I was using the code from IdentityServer4 QuickStart sample from [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/Quickstarts/4_ImplicitFlowAuthenticationWithExternal)

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            DisplayName = "Google",
            SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme,

            ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxx-Xxxxxxx"
        });
```

I had to change the code to the following to fix the issue.

```
        var CookieScheme= app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Value.Cookies.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
            DisplayName = "Google",
            SignInScheme = CookieScheme,

            ClientId = "xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxx-Xxxxxxx"
        });
```

Instead of just using the constant 'external' from the `IdentityServerConstants.ExternalAUthenticationScheme` I had to obtain the scheme used to identify external authentication cookies from the cookie options of the current identity system used by the app. That is what fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the info, good to know as I'm implementing IDS4 right now :)

Answer (score 3):

workaround helped me until it’s resolved by asp.net team

```
    // GET: /Account/AccessDenied
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult AccessDenied(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // workaround
        if (Request.Cookies["Identity.External"] != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've set `config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true` in `Startup.cs` and the `EmailConfirmed` field is `false` for an externally authenticated user (e.g. Facebook login), on subsequent logins, you'll be directed to the `Account/AccessDenied/` action method.

Comment: I have set the `EmailConfirmed` to `true` because it makes sense for the external login and it doesn't help